# Array of functions in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, callback

I need to create an object within array of functions which should be called inside of object. but **myObj.myFunctions** is always undefined inside of my object after creation.

here is my example code

```js
var myObj = {
      myValue:"My Callback function has been Called",
      myFunctions: [this.myCallback,this.myCallback2],
      init: function(){
        //I need to call this.myFunctions[0...etc]  as callback
        //this.myFunctions[0]() //<-- Here is the error
        console.log(this.myFunctions); //<-- always undefined
      },
      myCallback:function(){
         console.log(this.myValue);
      },
      myCallback2:function(){
         console.log(this.myValue+" Second Callback");
      }
}
var createObject = Object.create(myObj);
createObject.init();
```

any idea how could I create array of functions as property of main object?
Thanks

Comment: The value of `this` is not affected by the object initializer; specifically `this` does **not** refer to the object that's being initialized; it has the same value as `this` in the enclosing context.

Comment: Thanks for your light speed fast answer, but how can I solve this problem? I spent hour on google even [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) wont help me

Comment: First, your clear intent is to initialize this _thing_ by running those methods. So you should just call the methods in the `init()` method and be done with the array mess. Second, you should consider best practices with JavaScript objects and write either a proper Constructor function or a Class. Answer: call the functions directly and skip the array mess.

Comment: Is `Object.create` a requirement? Why not use a prototype for these?

Answer (score 2):

> You need to **Create a function inside your myFunctions and return those array of callbacks**:

**Method #1**

```
var myObj = {
  myValue:"My Callback function has been Called",
  myFunctions: function () {                       // Assign a function and return those array of callbacks
    return [this.myCallback,this.myCallback2];
  },
  init: function(){
    return this.myFunctions();
  },
  myCallback:function(){
    console.log(this.myValue);
  },
  myCallback2:function(){
    console.log(this.myValue+" Second Callback");
  }
};

var createObject = Object.create(myObj);
var functions    = createObject.init();

console.log(functions);    // [f(), f()] 
                           // f for short-term of 'function'
```

**Method #2 - Using direct () function call is already supported for cleaner code**

```
var myObj = {
  myValue:"My Callback function has been Called",
  myFunctions() { 
    return [this.myCallback, this.myCallback2] 
  },
  init() { 
    return this.myFunctions(); 
  },
  myCallback(){
    console.log(this.myValue);
  },
  myCallback2(){
    console.log(this.myValue+" Second Callback");
  }
};
```

**Method #3 - Using ES6 Spread Operator and Replace 'this' to 'myObj'**

```
const myObj = {
  myValue:"My Callback function has been Called",
  myFunctions: () => [myObj.myCallback, myObj.myCallback2],
  init: () => myObj.myFunctions(),
  myCallback: () => console.log(myObj.myValue),
  myCallback2: () => console.log(`${myObj.myValue} Second Callback`)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept which you are fighting against is the meaning of `this` when you call/host your callback functions inside of the array. When done that way `this` becomes the `array` and thus you do not get the expected result. One way to get that result could be using `call` and transform your object so it can be instantiated like this:

```js
var myObj = function() {
  this.myValue = "My Callback function has been Called",
  this.init = function() {
    this.myFunctions[0].call(this)  // <-- pass the proper `this`
    this.myFunctions[1].call(this)
  },
  this.myCallback = function() {
    console.log(this.myValue);
  },
  this.myCallback2 = function() {
    console.log(this.myValue + " Second Callback");
  },
  this.myFunctions = [this.myCallback, this.myCallback2]
}
var createObject = new myObj()
createObject.init();
```

Another way would be via `bind` but that is hardly recommended these days so I would skip it and head towards a recommendation which I think you should consider:

```js
class MyObj {
  constructor(val) {
    this.myValue = val;
  }
  myCallback() {
    console.log(this.myValue + " - First Callback");
  }
  myCallback2() {
    console.log(this.myValue + " - Second Callback");
  }
  get myCallbacks() {
    return ['myCallback', 'myCallback2']
  }
  init() {
    this[this.myCallbacks[0]]()  // <-- no issues with `this` anymore
    this[this.myCallbacks[1]]()
  }
}
var createObject = new MyObj('foo')
createObject.init();
```

Host your callback as `string keys` in your `myCallbacks` array in your class. That way you can call them via property accessor and not worry about the `this` context since at this time it would be the one you expect - the class.